# spring-batch getPage() returns 1

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have a batch job which we run every 1 hour. If the batch job runs for longer that 50 minutes we kill the current execution.

if the batch finished and exited gracefully, everything is good and in the next batch value returned by `getPage()` is 0. But if we killed the long-running batch, in the next batch `getPage()` value is 1 not 0.

Is the spring saving values between batches? where is context saved?

Answer (score 0):

When using stateful `ItemReader` implementations (those that implement the `ItemStream` interface), the state of the reader is persisted within the `ExecutionContext` and subsequently within the `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` or `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` tables.

You can read more about the `ExecutionContext` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ExecutionContext.html

You can also read about state management within Spring Batch here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#domainExecutionContext

Comment: We only have one table of all these tables. But, I don't see page information being saved anywhere. How the page can be 1 when we start the job?

Comment: Is there anything else we can chek? I see readCount being saved in `batch_job_param` table. But I don't see a relation where its being used